# error: unexpected if for unknown reasons

Tags: coffeescript

I don't have a clue why this happens, but here is code of the file:

```
express = require "express"
fs = require "fs"

router = express.Router()

module.exports = (config) ->

    fileRe = /^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(\.(png|jpg|jpeg))?$/i

    router.get '/:file', (req, res) ->

        file = req.params.file

        if !file or !fileRe.test file
            return res.error(404).send "404 Not Found"

        fileInfo = fileRe.exec file

        if !fileInfo[3]
            # .png is default if extension is ommited
            # abc => abc.png, but abc.jpg will stay
            file += ".png"

        if fs.access config.destination + file, fs.F_OK, (err) ->
            if err
                res.status(500).send "An error occured"
            else
                if !fileInfo[3] or fileInfo[3] == "png"
                    ct = "image/png"
                else if fileInfo[3] == "jpg"
                    ct = "image/jpg"

                opts =
                    lastModified: false
                    headers:
                        "Content-Disposition": "inline; filename=\"#{file}\""
                        "Content-Type": ""

    return router
```

I get the following error

```
/home/kindlyfire/Webroot/uplimg-server/src/web/view.coffee:24:9: error: unexpected if
    if fs.access config.destination + file, fs.F_OK, (err) ->
    ^^
```

I looked at the spaces, no problem there. Has anybody an idea about what it might be ?

Comment: Its the commas on that line. That is not syntactically valid coffeescript.

Comment: Just because you can use anonymous functions doesn't mean you should or must use them. Your code would be clearer and even syntactically correct if you named the `(err) ->` callback function in that broken `if`.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is not valid coffeescript. Specifically, it is the commas on the line the error is pointing you to. I'd offer info on how to fix it, but I can't even tell what you were trying to accomplish here. You *have* to provide a way for the compiler (not to mention *readers*) to be able to tell, unambiguously, what divisions you want in your code:

```
# fine
if foo then (a, b) -> c

# also fine
if foo
  (a, b) ->
    c

# ??
if foo (a, b) -> c

# ????
if foo a, b -> c
```

Repro of the [bug](http://coffeescript.org/#try:if%203%20%2B%202%2C%20'foo'%2C%20-%3E%0A%20%20console.log%20'foo'). Note that this is a good example of how to make a *minimum reproduction of the problem*. I highly, *highly* recommend you read a coffeescript style guide and discipline yourself to follow it. *Which* one is not terribly important, its the *consistency* that matters. Do not just randomly copy-paste stuff from the internets into your code, re-write it to follow the same style as the rest of your code. Doing so will often have the added benefit of realizing *how* the snippet you copied is working.